# error in training model in which training images are in class subfolders and test images are in another single folder

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-classification

I am trying to do binary classification of images. The images present are of two types, say class 'A' and class 'B'
The structure of my folder is :

```
data/
    train/
         class 'A' images folder/
               1.jpg
               2.jpg .......
         class 'B' images folder/
               1.jpg
               2.jpg .......
    test/
        only images without any labels
    csv file containing test images name and their label/
        1.jpg  - 'A'
        2.jpg  - 'B'
```

I am running the following command, but it is giving error

```
model.fit_generator(
  training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs=10,
  steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
  validation_steps=len(test_set)
)
```

The error is : `ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))`
I am newbie to keras and hence don't know how to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you share complete code to replicate your issue, so that we can help you?

Comment: can you show your  ImageDataGenerator code?

Comment: need the ImageDataGenerator code and the model code in order to solve the problem